# A reason to celebrate

Tags: lateral-thinking, english

Due to a communication breakdown and some misunderstanding, a truck with four boxes (pictured) full of valuables was left unguarded and unlocked door for exactly 1 hour in front of the bank.

Each box weighed the same but the content in each was different.

Even though the passing thief had enough time to steal all four, he left the crate marked as "diamonds" untouched.

[image]

**Can you quickly deduce why?**

Comment: The answer is no. I cannot quickly deduce why. (that was easy)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The box with diamonds was upside down, so that the label "NO17" looked like "LION".  The thief did not want to tangle with a dangerous animal.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. That was quick.

Comment: I figured those labels were there for a reason. :D

Comment: I dunno... if I were a thief, I would take the lion and use him to help me fight the pursuing police.

Comment: Probably a good idea that the thief left the diamonds anyway - they're near worthless and have next to zero resale value. :P I mean, if the thief were smart, that would have been the primary reason. But then, a box filled to the brim with diamonds that weighed as much as a box of gold would be huge and unwieldy, but quite a conversation starter in your mansion.

Comment: A box big enough to hold a lion filled with gold or platinum (or probably even silver or diamonds) would be far too heavy for one thief to lift.  For that matter, lions are pretty heavy too - did he happen to have a forklift?  Plus you'd think a box with a live lion in it would also have air-holes, or it wouldn't be alive for very long, and lion pelts probably are probably worth a decent price on the black market...  /overthinking

Comment: With the other boxes there it should be quite obvious that they're numbered, and that the box doesn't in fact contain a lion. Unless the thief managed to steal, transport, and unload the other three boxes without seeing any of the numbered labels on them...

Comment: i'm surprised it is valid answer, if i had a choice, i would definitely go for lion. why do you need some old gold or silver rubbish if you can have a nice lion?

Answer (score 14):

I have a guess, though it may not be correct.

> The other three are metals that can be melted down and effectively obscured as "stolen", while diamonds are useless if changed and will typically have identifying information laser-cut into them.

Comment: Logically that is a correct answer. I am looking for a simpler explanation. Definitely an Upvote from me.

Answer (score 11):

The density of diamonds is 1/5 the density of gold.  So if the thief had stolen the box of gold and realized that it was full, he would know that it would require five times the volume of diamonds to weigh the same amount.  Since the boxes were all roughly the same size, the thief easily determined that the diamonds were fakes.

Comment: That is an interesting take on the answer.

Comment: Or the box containing the gold was only 1/5 full.

Answer (score 3):

> The boxes are stacked, and so if the thief sees the gold and platinum boxes in front, the diamonds are hidden from view. You can't see box 17 unless you moved the other boxes out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no way anybody could have a box with that many diamonds in it and entrust it to a bank.  Banks might keep precious metals but they don't usually keep diamonds.

Therefore the thief was afraid it had some kind of police tracking device.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but wouldn't that logic apply to other boxes too?

Comment: Well, banks may keep precious metals - this is way more normal than keeping diamonds; therefore diamonds are suspicious.